# Getting an exception "Cannot access a disposed object." when performing second operation on the same mvc page

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have an MVC 5 application that is using for some part EF Core to access the database. I'm using SimpleInjector and Repository pattern.

I've registered my MainContext as

```
container.Register(() => new MainContext(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IARSMLayer,ARSMLayer>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

So from the documentation, I'm expecting that the SI is responsible for the life of the MainContext.

Inside my code, I init it as

```
     public ARSMLayer(IARSMLayerRepository arsmLayerRepository, IALayerOld aLayer, MainContext mainContext, ILog log)
    {
        this.aLayer = aLayer;
        this.mainContext = mainContext;
        this.log = log;
    }
```

and after the data are loaded I click on a button that uses the MainContext to perform operations.

If I re-click the button the second time I got the following exception

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed of the object. A common 
>       cause of this error is disposing of a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing of context instances.
>   Object name: 'MainContext'.'

Now I've checked and when I click on the button I got a different MainContext object, so I don't understand why it says it's accessing to a disposed of object

BTW wasn't supposed to be "safe" since it's registered as scoped?

The exception is thrown here

```
  public int GetAxParentela(int idParentela)
    {

        var recordParentela = mainContext.GradoParentela.Where(m => m.IdGradoParentela == idParentela).Single(); //HERE

        return recordParentela.IdAx.HasValue ? recordParentela.IdAx.Value : -1;

    }
```

Comment: how you are injecting it?

Comment: from the constructor as you can see from the snippet

Comment: There is nothing in your provided code fragments that explains this error. Can you provide the code where the exception is thrown and highlight the line that throws the exception?

Comment: Ok, that doesn't help. Can you provide the code that allows us see what happens when you click the button. From a server perspective you cannot "click a button" you can send a request. So it could help if you could provide the request too.

Comment: We already know what happens when we reach the exception throwing line. What we need to see is the other piece(s) of code that also interact with this context object earlier during the request.

Comment: How are you registering `ARSMLayer` and how are you registering the consumers of `ARSMLayer`? Do you call `Container.Verify()` at the end of the registration phase? Does `Verify()` throw an exception? And if so, what's the message? At the moment, your question is too broad, and does not contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited my post and added the ARSMLayer registration. I use ```Verify()``` and it doesn't throw an exception or warning

Comment: @advapi: Please post a full stack trace.

Comment: The registrations you show are fine. The problem lies somewhere else. You are probable holding on to either `ARSMLayer` or one of its consumers after the request has finished. Try placing a break point in the `ARSMLayer`'s constructor to see how often it is created.